# How to create a drop down style warning view like Instagram did?

Tags: ios, uitableview, drop-down-menu, uialertview

In the Instagram app, when the app checks for user input (like username or email address), if something goes wrong, it will bring up a drop down style warning view at the top of the window, and it will automatically dismiss. I like the way ,and I think it's better than a standard pop up UIAlertView.

I know Apple doesn't provide a standard control for that. Anyone know how to do that? Can I use a single row table view to mimic the behavior ?

Comment: Not everyone uses Instagram. Update your question to describe what you want without referencing another app. Also include what effort or research you've done so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a customize view for this type of controls. Though there is a lot of controls like this and most of them are customizable. [This control](https://github.com/ChrisXu1221/CXCardView) might be useful.